# Extract json values into columns if certain id exists

Tags: mysql, json

I have some db that stores json array of objects in a column. I need to make columns out of these objects keys if object's id has certain value

My documents table is simple:

```
id |   name    | percent_split
1  | some name | [ {id: 59, share:22, value: 55},{id:58, share:40, value:33}]
```

I've tried some variants of the following to get the data, not mentioning making columns out of object keys:

```
SELECT 
id, name, 
(SELECT FROM documents 
    WHERE (
    CASE WHEN JSON_VALID(percent_split) THEN 
    json_search(percent_split, 'one', '{"id":"59"}') 
    ELSE null 
    END)
) AS result_for_59
FROM documents
```

I would like to get additional columns in the result of my query

```
id, name, 59_share, 59_value, NN_share, NN_value
```

Please help :)

I could go with any language easily, but in this case I'm limited to use only MySql technology.

Comment: Looks like you need dynamic number of columns, and SQL is not suitable tool for the same. Consider handling data display related requirements in your application code, eg: PHP, Java etc

Comment: Thanks Madhur, but I'm limited to mysql use in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made a function in mysql which has two arguments: the column_value and the value we search for:

```
RETURN JSON_EXTRACT(value, JSON_UNQUOTE(
    REPLACE(
        JSON_SEARCH(
            ,'one',column_value
        ),'.id','.share'
    ))
)
```

Then we call it inside select part of query, for every value we need:

```
if(json_valid(percent_split),get_share(39, percent_split),NULL) AS share39
```